# Multiple audio addresses snap to items HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Need help web developer.
How to register in the function jquery several, many audio addresses (url) and bind these addresses of mp3 files to elements from html

```
<h2>W</h2>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<br>
<h2>E</h2>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>


$(document).ready(function() {
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3');
```

Comment: please avoid taking screenshot of your code, it is bad practice. please paste the code in the question and enclose it in the code tag located on the wysiwyg component when you ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var addresses = ["http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3" ];
var body = document.getElementById("audios");
let audiohtml = [];
addresses.map((address, i)=> {
  audiohtml.push(`<audio id='myAudio${i}' src=${address} preload='auto'></audio>
<br><h2>E</h2>
<button onClick=togglePlay(${i})>Play</button>
<button onClick=togglePause(${i})>Pause</button>`)
});
body.innerHTML= audiohtml;
function togglePlay(i) {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById(`myAudio${i}`);
    myAudio.play();
};
function togglePause(i) {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById(`myAudio${i}`);
    myAudio.pause()
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body id='audios'>

</body>
</html>
```

for more details:  https://jsbin.com/sejuzoz/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Замечательно, проверила, всё прекрасно работает! Век  живи и век учись!) Благодарю вас!

Comment: Отметка засчиталась? новичок на сайте, разбираюсь в функциях сайта